# HTML table only dash in the middle

Tags: html, css, html-table

I would like to make a dash in the middle of a table. 
The first picture shows my current state and the second picture shows how I would like it. 
How do I get the line?

```
 <table>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="https://thunder.cdn.overdrive.com/logos/crushed/1211.png?1" alt="Logo" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <strong><font color=darkgrey>Tel.:</font></strong> <font color=grey>+44(0) XXX</font>
            <br/>
            <strong><font color=darkgrey>E-Mail:</font></strong> <font color=grey>xxx@xxx.com</font>
            <br/>
            <strong><font color=darkgrey>Web:</font></strong> <font color=grey>www.xxx.com</font>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

[image: PIC1]
[image: PIC2]

Comment: in css you can use: border-left: 1 px dotted black;

Comment: add to your HTML: `<style> tr { border-left: 1px dashed gray; } </style>`

Comment: How is that tabular content? Or is this for HTML email?

Comment: For a HTML email.

Comment: `<td style="border-left: 2px dotted #bbb">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use `border-left` property to create a dotted grey line:

```
border-left: 2px dotted grey;
```

You will notice that that goes right on the text, so the next step is to add `padding-left` to move the text away from the dotted line.

Working example:

```css
#add {
    border-left: 2px dotted grey;
    padding-left: 14px;
}
```

```html
 <table>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="https://thunder.cdn.overdrive.com/logos/crushed/1211.png?1" alt="Logo" />
        </td>
        <td id="add">
            <strong><font color=darkgrey>Tel.:</font></strong> <font color=grey>+44(0) XXX</font>
            <br/>
            <strong><font color=darkgrey>E-Mail:</font></strong> <font color=grey>xxx@xxx.com</font>
            <br/>
            <strong><font color=darkgrey>Web:</font></strong> <font color=grey>www.xxx.com</font>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

You can do this inline as well:

```
<td style="border-left: 2px dotted grey; padding-left: 14px;">
```

It is also important to create an `id` as well and not just use `td` element or you will get this result:

```css
td {
    border-left: 2px dotted grey;
    padding-left: 14px;
}
```

```html
 <table>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="https://thunder.cdn.overdrive.com/logos/crushed/1211.png?1" alt="Logo" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <strong><font color=darkgrey>Tel.:</font></strong> <font color=grey>+44(0) XXX</font>
            <br/>
            <strong><font color=darkgrey>E-Mail:</font></strong> <font color=grey>xxx@xxx.com</font>
            <br/>
            <strong><font color=darkgrey>Web:</font></strong> <font color=grey>www.xxx.com</font>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

(two dotted lines will appear)